# Python Tkinter frame newby geometry problem?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

I am very new in tkinter and python. Thats how my code looks:

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()
# Window size
main.geometry("400x700")
main.resizable(0, 0)

# Window position
w = main.winfo_reqwidth()
h = main.winfo_reqheight()
ws = main.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = main.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
main.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))

fr1 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg = "#271ee3", width=400, height=50)
fr2 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg = "#0d9467", width=200, height=650)
fr3 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg = "#3e1854", width=200, height=650)

fr1.pack()
fr2.pack(side="left")
fr3.pack(side="right")

main.mainloop()
```

With this code I get the 
[following window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqVCH.png)

So far so good. The problem comes when i add this code:

```
# Label
l = tk.Label(fr2, text="Heyho")
l.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Now it looks [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIiHW.png)

My goal is to get a window where i have in the first frame (fr1) a button that has the same geometry like fr1. In fr2 und fr3 I want to have severel labels among each other. My labels in fr2 und fr3 should have column 0 but ascending rows (0,1,2,3...). How can I do it??

Comment: it automatically resize frame to label's size so you don't see green background which is hidden behind label - and you see main window's gray background. If you add `fr2.grid_propagate(False)` then it will not resize Frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It automatically resize Frame to Label's size so you don't see green background which is hidden behind label - and you see main window's gray background.

You can see it better if you add other longer label and red background in main window

[image]

If you add

```
fr2.grid_propagate(False)
```

then frame will keep its size

[image]

but you still have problem with grid which doesn't use full size of `Frame` and you can't center it or align to right.

If you add

```
fr2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

then column 0 will try to use full size if there is no other columns, and label will be centered in cell

[image]

If you use

```
sticky='we'
```

in `grid()` for labels then they will fill cell

[image]

---

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()
# Window size
main.geometry("400x200")
main.resizable(0, 0)
main['bg'] = 'red'
# Window position
w = main.winfo_reqwidth()
h = main.winfo_reqheight()
ws = main.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = main.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
main.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))

fr1 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg = "#271ee3", width=400, height=50)
fr2 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg = "#0d9467", width=200, height=650)
fr3 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg = "#3e1854", width=200, height=650)

fr1.pack()
fr2.pack(side="left")
fr3.pack(side="right")


fr2.grid_propagate(False)
fr2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

l1 = tk.Label(fr2, text="Heyho")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')

l2 = tk.Label(fr2, text="Hello World")
l2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem! But now when i change row=2 for l2 then nothink changes. I want to have l1 in row 0. row 1 should be empty and in row 2 I want to habe an other label.

Comment: empty row/column has height/width zero - so you can't see difference. You have to put element with some size in row 1 or you have to set minimal height for row 1 -  `f1.grid_rowconfig(1, minsize=...)`

Comment: you can also add `pad y` in row 0 to get distance - it can be `pady=(top,bottom)` or `pady=both` -  `l1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we', pady=(0, 5))` or `l1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we', pady=5)`